# nonlinear increase of computation time of listplot

Tags: plotting

consider the following example

```
testsmall = RandomReal[{-1.5, 1.5}, {1000, 3}];
testbig = RandomReal[{-1.5, 1.5}, {10000, 3}];

Timing[ListPlot[Style[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, If[#[[3]] < 0., White, Blue]] & /@ testsmall]]
Timing[ListPlot[Style[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, If[#[[3]] < 0., White, Blue]] & /@ testbig]]
```

For me the drawing of the first graph takes around 0.7 sec and for the second one (note it has 10 times more points to check the condition on) around 60 sec. Why does the amount of time increase nonlinearly and more importantly, what can I do to fix this/make this faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't use `ListPlot` to plot a bunch of styled points like that, handling these kind of list is doomed to be inefficient. Instead use `Graphics`:

```
Timing@Graphics[{If[#[[3]] < 0., White, Blue], 
     Point[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}]} & /@ testsmall]
Timing@Graphics[{If[#[[3]] < 0., White, Blue], 
     Point[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}]} & /@ testbig]
```

Comment: (+1)  using `Graphics[Point[testbig[[All, {1, 2}]], 
  VertexColors -> (Sign[testbig[[All, 3]]] /. {-1 -> White, 
      1 -> Blue})]]` makes it even faster.